# The most efficient way to match two collections and run async code if match is not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections, one contains my static items and other collection contains reverse geocode results for that item. They are matched by `id` property.

I am writing a script that would fill reverse geocode collection with missing items.

This is my current solution which is super slow, it does:

- Get total count of static items
- Create read stream from static items collection
- Uses find one on reverse geocode collection for each item that comes from the read stream
- If items exists, increase counter by 1 and ignore it
- If item doesn't exist, fetch it from API, save it to collection and increase counter by 1
- When counter is equal total count, it means all items are fetched, 
  therefore resolve function

  ```
  function fetchMissingData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const staticData = Global.state.db.collection('static_data')
      const googleData = Global.state.db.collection('google_reverse_geocode')

    staticData.count((countErr, count) => {
      if (countErr) return reject(countErr)
      let counter = 0
      let fetched = 0

      function finishIfReady(){
        process.stdout.write(`Progress...(${counter}/${count}), (fetched total: ${fetched})\r`)
        if (count === counter) {
          resolve({ fetched, counter })
        }
      }

      staticData.find()
      .on('data', (hotel) => {
        googleData.findOne({ id: hotel.id }, (findErr, geocodedItem) => {
          if (findErr) return reject(findErr)
          if (geocodedItem) {
            counter++
            finishIfReady()
          } else {
            GMClient.reverseGeocode({ latlng: hotel.geo }, (err, response) => {
              if (err) return reject(err)
              googleData.insertOne({
                id: hotel.id,
                payload: response,
              }).then(() => {
                fetched++
                counter++
                finishIfReady()
              }).catch(e => reject(e))
            })
          }
        })
      })
      .on('error', e => reject(e))
    })
  })
  }
  ```

Is there more elegant solution using aggregation framework that would allow me same behavior without <s>O(n^{2})</s> O(nlogn) complexity?

Comment: suggest you to move the part googleData.insertOne(...).then(...) to await googleData.insertOne(...). Will do the same and will remove one level. Not sure that it solves your problem. And transform you function fetchMissingData to async fetchMissingData. Will allow you to remove the line 2 (return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {)

Comment: @MathKimRobin Yes this improves readability, but these are just syntax sugars which are actually the same thing performance-wide. In this example, I am using plain promises instead of async/await because of support towards older version of Node.

Comment: OK thanks for the course. Was not sure. Not really good at calculating complexity

Answer (score 1):

First, the actual complexity is O(nlogn) because `findOne` on `id` use binary search. Second, although there is no way to pass the theory complexity O(nlogn) in this case, there is way to help make your code faster in practice. This is what I would do:

```
function getIdOfAllGeoData() {
    // return an array of existing Geo data IDs
    return Global.state.db.collection('google_reverse_geocode')
        .find().toArray().map(o => o.id);
}

function getStaticDataMissingGeo(existingGeoDataIds) {
    const staticData = Global.state.db.collection('static_data');

    return staticData.find({
        id: {
            $nin: existingGeoDataIds
        }
    }).toArray();
}

function fetchMissingData() {
    const existingGeoDataIds = getIdOfAllGeoData();
    const staticDataMissingGeo = getStaticDataMissingGeo(existingGeoDataIds);

    // staticDataMissingGeo is all the static that need geo data
    // you can loop through this array, get each items geo data and insert to database

    // ...
}
```

Finally, you could use `bulk` operation to speed thing up, it will be much faster. Also, my mongo related code above may not be correct, consider it as an idea.

Comment: I see your idea, but how would this code work on huge amounts of data?